# How to send BNB in BSC mainnet using Web3

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, bsc

I am going to send BNB using web3 on BSC main net.
BSC mainnet is as follow.

```
MAINNET=https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.MAINNET);
const BNBcontract = await new web3.eth.Contract(BNBabi, process.env.BNB_ADDRESS);
const BNBdecimals = await BNBcontract.methods.decimals().call();
```

But it happens error when I run the code

> Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might
> also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the
> contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block
> number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully
> synced.

My idea is wrong?
I can't send BNB on BSC main net?
And what is BNB token address?
I found the BNB token address in Etherscan.io.
0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52
This is right?
And I should use contract ABI on etherscan.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const web3 = new Web3(req.body.network && req.body.network === "MAINNET" ? process.env.MAINNET : process.env.TESTNET);

try {
    // Sign transaction
    let signTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
        to: req.body.to,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(req.body.amount, 'ether'),
        gas: req.body.gas || 2000000
    }, req.body.from_private_key);

    // Transaction
    let tx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signTransaction.rawTransaction
    );
    
    res.status(200).send({ status: true, hash: tx.transactionHash });
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ status: false, message: 'Transfer Failed' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const privateKey = '<YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY>';
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/');
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const toAddress = '0xRecipientAddress'; // Replace with the recipient's BSC address.
const valueToBeSend = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.1', '18'); // Replace with the amount of BNB you want to send (in BNB)

async function sendBNB() {
  const tx = await wallet.sendTransaction({
    to: toAddress,
    value: valueToBeSend
  });

  await tx.wait();
  console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);
}

sendBNB();
```

You can also use ether.js for sending BNB to an BSC account. Also for sending BNB we dont need any ABI.

The script above can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const signedTx = await  web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
  to: account.address,
  value: (process.env.BNB_SEND_AMOUNT* 10**decimals).toString(),
  gas: 2000000,
  common: {
    customChain: {
      name: 'custom-chain',
      chainId: 56,
      networkId: 56
    }
  }
}, process.env.MAIN_WALLET_PRIVATE);
        
// BNB send
let BNBtx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);

// BNB hash
console.log("BNB Hash: ", BNBtx.transactionHash)
```

For sending BNB on BSC, we don't need ABI file of BNB.